# neo4j - match nodes and add relationships to them

Tags: neo4j

how do i add relationships to nodes returned by a cypher query?

I have written a query that returns me all the person nodes who have the same surname who live at the same address.  I now want to add a relationship between these person nodes to indicate they are the same person.  The query below returns me 3 person nodes and I want to add a relationship from the first node (returned by the ORDER BY) to the other 2.

```
MATCH (a:Address) <-[LIVES_AT]-(p:Person)
WITH a as addnode, p.surname as psurname,  COUNT(p.name_urn) as c
WHERE c > 1
MATCH (a2:Address{address_urn:addnode.address_urn})<-[LIVES_AT]-  (p2:Person{surname:psurname})
WITH p2 as p2node
ORDER BY CASE
         WHEN p2node.master_record = 'Y' 
         THEN 
           1
         ELSE
           2
         END
WITH collect(p2node) as colp2node
RETURN colp2node
```

Hope this makes sense? Please advise if there is a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work for you:

```
MATCH (a:Address)<-[LIVES_AT]-(p:Person)
WITH a, p.surname AS psurname, COUNT(p.name_urn) AS c
WHERE c > 1
MATCH (a2:Address { address_urn:a.address_urn })<-[LIVES_AT]-(p2:Person { surname:psurname })
WITH p2
ORDER BY CASE WHEN p2.master_record = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END 
WITH collect(p2) AS colp2
WITH colp2[0] AS master, colp2[1..] AS others
UNWIND others AS other
MERGE (master)-[:HAS_ALIAS]->(other);
```

I use `MERGE` to avoid duplicate relationships.

*By the way, just because two people have the same surname and live at the same address, that does not normally mean they are the same person. I hope you are sure that what you are doing is appropriate.*

Comment: Cheers cybersam worked a treat ... and yeah was just using the surname matching as a test ... cheers for commenting :)